# ClassNotFoundException in IBM Websphere 8.5 application server

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have deployed the Ear file on IBM Websphere 8.5  AS.
When I am using my application it is giving me one
ClassNotFoundException but class for which it is giving the exception is in jar file which already in the ear file.
So, can you please tell me what is the cause of this problem?
Do we need to configure some thing  in websphere AS so that it will add these jars in to classpath?

Comment: Please provide the full exception stack trace and a description of the layout of the application (how the JARs are packaged, which JARs contain which classes, which JARs have MANIFEST.MF, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got resolved,There is manifest file inside the EML.war file which is inside the ECM.Ear I added the jar file name under the classpath inside the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

@user3036097 - WAS 8.5 may be providing the same jar albeit a different version of that jar that's missing your required class.  You could try setting the Classloader Policy to PARENT_LAST.  This configuration can be found in deployment.xml within your ear project.  If you're using RAD, you can right-click on your ear project and select "Open Application Deployment Descriptor".